# Is asio4all compatible with bluetooth headsets?

Tags: sound

My question is simple. Is asio4all compatible with bluetooth headsets? If it's yes, can somebody give me an information about what kind of bluetooth headset I should use? I use Ableton Live 10 intro.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on sound.stackexchange.com

Comment: What kind of topic is this then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a personal audio device.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth headsets aren't a good idea for music production because of the high latency.  Make your life easy and use wired ones.

Comment: I do use wired ones. The reason why I need bluetooth is because of recording. I play the violin and it's way easier to record with bluetooth headset compared to wired ones. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: May be easier.  But if you're playing to a track delayed by the latency of the Bluetooth system....